# I need help replicating this cool jQuery/javascript/css effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I really like the transition and effects used on this site: http://imagemechanics.com.au/. I would like to replicate this on a site I'm working on, but my CSS and Javascript skills are not there yet. The site said it's "nothing too special behind the scenes of the site - all done with css, jquery, ajax..."

Are there any jQuery kits out there that does the same effect? Or is there an easy way to pull the code needed from the site to replicate it myself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should start with learning so your css/javascript skills become better.. and try it bit by bit... look at jQuery and what you can do with it. Remember to  to things step by step don't go for the biggest best and hardest the first time.. it won't succeed

Comment: Have a look at the site's Javascript and CSS, especially http://imagemechanics.com.au/media/j/site.js?v2, check out jQuery's `animate()` function, and jQuery UI and start building something — we'll be happy to help you out whenever you hit a wall. I doubt someone's going to hand you the code ready or help you to "replicate" another site, though. Trial and error, that's the way you learn ;) .

Comment: @BvdVen, @polarblau why don't you add an answer?

Comment: @Agos I don't see my reply as an answer. crashintoty isn't able to go and develop the thing he asked, after reading my answer. I just wanted to let him know he shouldn't aim to high :)

Comment: @Agos: He's asking where he can get the "effects" he has seen somewhere ready as "kit" or how he can "replicate" it by "pulling the code needed from the site". — The first question I can't answer, the second I'm reluctant to answer. I can understand his position, and it's a good place to start: "You see something cool and want to do the same or something similar." We all have been there to some degree and I'm happy to help if I can. But there's no question here that I could answer. He'll have to start digging a little first…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check jquery scrollTo();

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html